# Call result controller/view in anoter view

Tags: symfony, view, controller, include, render

I try to call controller/view in another view. I have a homepage `Default:index` using a block view of my controller `Event` and I want to put this `block.html.twig` in my folder of my controller. In my controller Event, I want an action block, in this way I keep the logic of events, in my controller Event.

How can I do for in `Event:index.html.twig` call my controller/view ?
I saw the helper render, but I think it makes many requests to include the result.

Comment: The helper render is what you are searching for. Sub requests are not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track. When calling sub-renders from a view, you have several options, as detailed here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

The one I think you're looking for is:

```
{{ render(controller('YourBundle:Event:index')) }}
```

which will call the controller action and relevant view.

As an aside, if you want a sub-render, but require no controller logic, use

```
{{ include('YourBundle:Event:index.html.twig') }}
```

as this seems to be a lot more lightweight.

If you need to use any of these with parameters, normal format is used.